# Difference between two dates having maximum days in between from a group having common id

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, date-difference, groupwise-maximum

If I take the dates from the Group B, then I have to find the maximum difference between any two dates from the group B and display that days_difference as a separate column. Also want to display those two dates in two different columns which had maximum days_difference.

Condition: Two class id may have same Class-Name in the data. As you can see Class-ID 1238 and 1252 have same Class-Name. So output should be for every class-id

So result should have: ClassID, ClassName, Date1 , Date 2, DateDiff

```
ClassName | Dates     | ClassID  | Spend($)
ClassA    | 21-Jun-16 | 1238     | 1
ClassA    | 27-Jun-16 | 1238     | 2
ClassA    | 14-Apr-11 | 1252     | 3
ClassA    | 15-Apr-11 | 1252     | 4
ClassC    | 26-Oct-15 | 1261     | 5
ClassC    | 21-Oct-15 | 1261     | 6
ClassA    | 10-Dec-10 | 1252     | 21
ClassC    | 15-Dec-14 | 1261     | 23
ClassC    | 15-May-14 | 1261     | 34
ClassA    | 10-Jan-09 | 1252     | 54
ClassA    | 12-Jun-09 | 1238     | 65
ClassA    | 29-Jun-12 | 1238     | 76
ClassA    | 11-Apr-08 | 1252     | 87
ClassA    | 01-Apr-16 | 1252     | 56
ClassC    | 16-Oct-16 | 1261     | 43
ClassC    | 02-Sep-05 | 1261     | 33
ClassA    | 29-Dec-13 | 1252     | 77
ClassC    | 13-Dec-15 | 1261     | 87
ClassC    | 13-Aug-10 | 1261     | 98
ClassA    | 21-Jan-14 | 1252     | 12
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: What is "Group B"?  Nothing in your data sample refers to this.

Comment: I am sorry. Actually you can only consider the ClassID in this case and consider it to make a group.

Comment: If there are four dates for One ID then I have to find which two consecutive dates for that ID had maximum difference in days

Comment: There are LAG and LEAD options to get the previous or next date and compare to current row

Comment: For example if there are 50 records for one id with 50 dates, then I have to find out two consecutive dates(NOT max and min dates) from those 50 dates which have maximum days difference. Will have to apply this for other id's in the table.

Comment: Can somebody please help me

Answer (score 0):

you can get the day difference between sequential dates by use LEAD or LAG.

```
SELECT 
    Dates,
    LEAD(Dates) OVER (PARTITION BY ClassID ORDER BY Dates) NextDate,
    Dates - LEAD(Dates) OVER (PARTITION BY ClassID ORDER BY Dates) DaysDiff
FROM MyTable
```

you can get the result you want from this result by taking the record with the highest DaysDiff value

[**for reference**](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions)

to rank the results and get the highest ranked date diff per classID.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ClassID ORDER BY DaysDiff DESC) Rnk
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            ClassID,
            ClassName,
            Dates,
            LEAD(Dates) OVER (PARTITION BY ClassID ORDER BY Dates) NextDate,
            Dates - LEAD(Dates) OVER (PARTITION BY ClassID ORDER BY Dates) DaysDiff
        FROM MyTable) t1
    ) t2
WHERE t2.Rnk = 1
```

the output for the above sample data should be.

```
ClassName ClassID     Dates                   NextDate                DaysDiff    Rnk
--------- ----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------- --------------------
ClassA    1238        2012-06-29 00:00:00.000 2016-06-21 00:00:00.000 1453        1
ClassA    1252        2011-04-15 00:00:00.000 2013-12-29 00:00:00.000 989         1
ClassC    1261        2005-09-02 00:00:00.000 2010-08-13 00:00:00.000 1806        1
```

Comment: But I want the difference which is maximum between the sequential dates. Not calculating difference between all sequential dates and displaying it.

Comment: @RohitJachak i was just giving you a starting point, but i've updated the answer to use the RANK function to get the highest date diff records.

Comment: I have actually updated the question totally. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.ClassId,
       B.LagDates,
       B.Dates 
  FROM 
     (
         SELECT ClassId,
                MAX( DaysDiff ) AS MD
           FROM
              (       
                SELECT *,
                       LAG( Dates, 1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ClassID ORDER BY Dates ) AS LagDates,   
                       TO_DATE( Dates, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) 
                       -
                       LAG( Dates, 1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ClassID ORDER BY    
                       Dates ) AS DaysDiff
                  FROM ( SELECT *                                    
                           FROM Table
                          ORDER BY ClassId, Dates 
                        ) 
               ) 
         GROUP BY ClassId
      ) A,
      (
          SELECT *,
                 LAG( Dates, 1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ClassID ORDER BY Dates ) AS LagDates, 
                 TO_DATE( Dates, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) 
                 -
                 LAG( Dates, 1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ClassID ORDER BY Dates ) 
                 AS DaysDiff
            FROM (
                    SELECT * 
                      FROM Table
                     ORDER BY ClassId, Dates  
                  ) 
       ) B
WHERE A.ClassId = B.ClassId
  AND A.MD = B.DaysDiff;
```

Comment: What if I have to join two tables ? Where should I specify my join condition?

Comment: @RohitJachak - you specify your join condition where it belongs. There was no mention of joins in your original question, why do you keep such details till after people answer your question? What do you need to join - a table in your inputs? The output of this query? Something in between?

Comment: @Teja Hi. I have actually updated the question totally. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @mathguy I have updated my question. Sorry for inconvenience.